# Form submitting using Ajax?

Tags: ajax, forms

My form submits and it shouldn't as I am using aJax?! If I remove the form tag and closing form tag then it works but doesn't upload the image

```
$('#savebutton').click(function() {
preventDefault();
var val1 = $('#rsPubName').val();
var val2 = $('#address').val();
var val3 = $('#rsLat').val();
var val4 = $('#rsLong').val();
var val5 = $('#add2').val();
var val6 = $('#rsTown').val();
var val7 = $('#rsCounty').val();
var val8 = $('#rsPostCode').val();
var val9 = $('#region').val();
var val10 = $('#PremisesType').val();
var val11 = $('#rsTel').val();
var val12 = $('#rsWebsite').val();
var val13 = $('#rsAboutpub').val();
var val14 = $('#img1').val();
var val15 = $('#offer1').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addpub-script.php',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: { rsPubName: val1, address: val2, rsLat: val3, rsLong: val4, add2: val5, rsTown: val6, rsCounty: val7, rsPostCode: val8, region: val9, PremisesType: val10, rsTel: val11, rsWebsite: val12, rsAboutpub: val13, img1: val14, offer1: val15},
    success: function(response) {
        $('#result').html( '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><strong>New venue added!</strong> Why not <a href="#top" class="alert-link">add another?</a></div>').fadeIn()
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`preventDefault();` is a method on the `event` object. It should be:

```
$('#savebutton').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

where `event` is a passed in parameter prefilled by jQuery. See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#Methods) and the fourth method down.

Comment: Thanks, the form now submits but the image does not get uploaded

Comment: @user2924961 Glad the form submits. With regards to the upload problem, that should really be a separate question. However, I will say that I've had trouble with that before. Ajaxing files can be a little tricky. Since you're already using jQuery, you may be interested in this: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ plugin which abstracts this functionality away for you and even has an iFrame fallback for browsers that don't support ajaxing of files.